# Chart.js - How to hide tooltip on mouse over if all legends of pie chart is deselected?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am plotting pie chart with chart.js. It shows tooltip on mouseover over segments. When I deselect all legends, then it pie chart appears blank. But when you try to move mouse over area where chart were plotted, tooltip of first segment appear. How we can hide it?

I tried to remove line between segments but still tooltip appears. I used following code to remove line between segment

`options: {
    segmentShowStroke: false,
            elements: {
                            arc: {
                                   borderWidth: 0
                                 }
                           }
        }`

Tooltip still appears. If no sections are present in chart then no tooltip should appear.

[Please refer attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWAG4.png)

I have added link of my code: https://embed.plnkr.co/5v0h67kLyRHRwY5cT98f/

Thanks

Comment: Please post your chart rendering code or a fiddle?

Comment: I have added link of my code: https://embed.plnkr.co/5v0h67kLyRHRwY5cT98f/